# Add code in runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Let's say I have a list of strings. Based on the value of the strings I want to add code.

E.g., I have three strings; first name, last name, and e-mail address. They could be null or empty. Lets say last name and e-mail are empty, then I would like the following code:

```
repository.Find(dto => dto.FirstName == firstName)
          .Select(x => CreateAccount(x)).ToList();
```

When only email is empty, then the code should look like this:

```
accountRepository.Find(dto => dto.FirstName == firstName ||
                       dto.LastName == lastName)
                 .Select(x => CreateAccount(x)).ToList();
```

In other words, when looping through the strings, I want to add code when the strings are not empty. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Two keywords come to mind: Expression trees and CodeDOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify the Find predicate:

```
accountRepository.Find(dto => 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) ? false : dto.FirstName == firstName) || 
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) ? false : dto.LastName == lastName) ||
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) ? false : dto.Email == email))
    .Select(x => CreateAccount(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this works great! And no need to do something weird. Thanks!